# How to explain the strange output by "puts" in c++?

Tags: c++

I am reading a piece of code written by others, there is one line like this:

```
cout << "Data Loaded" <<　endl;
```

it seems nothing strange, however, the actually output is：

```
[18607330327, 18790481919] [19144201237, 19327352831] [20754813973, 20937965567] [21291684885, 21474836479] [21474836482, 21653864362] [22011707392, 22190735274] [23622320128, 23801348010] [24159191040, 24338218922] [27197264917, 27204255743] [27205653525, 27212644351] [27230819349, 27230959453] [27233615872, 27235153757] [30064771072, 30067638186] [30073159680, 30076026794] [30098325504, 30098440106] [30098456576, 30098536200] Data Loaded
```

where does the extra output come from? if I comment that line, then, nothing is output.

I then include the `<cstdio>` and replace that line by `puts("Data Loaded")`, still, the extra info get printed.

Comment: Please construct a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Maybe it's written *before* your output, by some other code you do not show us?

Comment: I think @JoachimPileborg nailed it. You're seeing output that was written earlier. Possibly it was not flushed and appeared just now due to the newline. Possibly it was there in the console or file, already.

Comment: It's impossible to say from the information you've provided.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, I use Qt to debug it and set breakpoint at this line, nothing is printed before this line. and that's why I can't give you a test-case. I really don't know how to repeat it.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, I set break point there and nothing got printed...+_+

Comment: @Alaya: Okay, then it was there in the cout output buffer. I.e. output that was done earlier, but not flushed. `std::endl` is defined as outputting a newline and then calling `.flush()` on the stream.

Comment: To generate a test case, you can always start by removing some code, checking that the error is still there, removing more code, etc., until the error disappears. Then you'll be much closer to a minimal test case (or to solving the problem yourself).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, I found you are right, it is because that there were some unflushed output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

cout is a buffered output stream, and endl not only creates a new line, it also flushes the buffer. Without the flushing of the buffer it might happen that you do not see the output of a previous cout.